# Angular 2 hide parent element on click on close button

Tags: angular, typescript1.8

I am new in Angular2, I want to hide parent element after clicking on the close icon. Below is my code:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'add-search',
    template: `
      <input type='text' #newHero
        (keyup.enter)="addHero(newHero.value)"
        (blur)="addHero(newHero.value); newHero.value='' ">
      <button (click)=addHero(newHero.value)>Add</button>
    <div>
    <div [hidden]="hideElement" style="margin-right:2px" *ngFor="let hero of heroes" class="label label-primary">{{hero}}<span (click)="toggleElement()" style='cursor:pointer; display:inline-block; padding:1px 2px;'><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:10px;"></i></span>
</div>
</div>
   `
})
export class AddSearchComponent {
    heroes = Array<string>();
    addHero(newHero: string) {
        if (newHero) {
            this.heroes.push(newHero);
        }
    }
    private hideElement: boolean = false;
    toggleElement() {
        if (this.hideElement) {
            this.hideElement = false;
        else
            this.hideElement = true;
    }
}
}
```

Hide is not working in code. Can we do it in a simple way? or what will be the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div [hidden]="hero.hideElement" style="margin-right:2px" 
     *ngFor="let hero of heroes" 
      class="label label-primary">{{hero}}

       <span (click)="hero.hideElement=!hero.hideElement"
              style='cursor:pointer; display:inline-block; padding:1px 2px;'>
              <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:10px;"></i>
       </span>
</div>

// toggle is not possible.
```

OR

```
<span  *ngFor="let hero of heroes"  
        (click)="hero.hideElement=!hero.hideElement"
        style='cursor:pointer; display:inline-block; padding:1px 2px;'>   
        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:10px;"></i>

    <div [hidden]="hero.hideElement" style="margin-right:2px"          
          class="label label-primary">
          {{hero}}    
    </div>
</span>

// toggle is possible.
```

**Update**:

You were not clear whether you are using **Array** or **Array of objects**.
SO I gave you solution of **Array of Objects**

With string array, it is not possible to hide an element with ***ngFor** loop. All you can do is **splice**.

Check both ways here.

**http://plnkr.co/edit/fc7x4nCh6vFIbIL2IX4I?p=preview**

Comment: Thanks @micronyks. Actually, I want to delete text after adding it on the page if required. I just tried it to achieve using the toggle. Unfortunately for me, it is not working as I said above.

Comment: So you can follow first suggestion. It will work. You don't required click event function in ts file. you can handle it from hTML itself as shown.

Comment: I am not able to close after clicking on the close icon in both suggestions.

Comment: Please check my both solutions carefully. If you are using HERO model then add `hideElement:boolean=false` property to that model. else suggested solutions must work.

Comment: thank you so much for your all effort. I may be doing some mistake. Please check live code [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/MvwGQPiTAjyjOqcSX9q3?p=preview)

Comment: Great! It is working now! Thank you so much @micronyks

Comment: So if it resolves your problem, you can accept it as an answer so it will be helpful for future readers .