# Show / Hide - Content on Button Click

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello fellow programmer,

im getting used to Angular 2, therefore Typescript, so have mercy with me.

I have 5 Buttons which should enable or Disable Content on Click, like a Sidemenu.

HTML - Code

```
  <li class="navigation-items"> 
    <button class="dropdown-header" (click)="onSelect(2)">Link 2</button> 
    <div *ngIf="DropdownVar == 2" class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
```

Typescript - Code

```
DropdownVar = 0;

onSelect(x){
 this.DropdownVar = x;
 console.log(x);
}
```

It seems that my var gets the propper value but my `*ngif` does not work.
Is there a better way to handle my Problem?

Additional i would like to have a little animation for the Content which i want to show, but i guess css is the way to go.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163009/angular-2-show-and-hide-an-element

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39651890/angular-2-hide-parent-element-on-click-on-close-button

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/XmDiJX3NhcSptZco2II5?p=preview

I just tried what you did and it's working (even though you really should use `===`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can directly do it with `(click)="DropdownVar=2"` , no need of `onSelect` method

```
 <li class="navigation-items"> 
        <button class="dropdown-header" (click)="DropdownVar=2">Link 2</button> 
        <div *ngIf="DropdownVar === 2" class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
```

And use `===` instead of `==` in Angular2

Comment: How those this answer the question ? ngIf should work even with what OP did. Besides, yes, in javascript in general, you should use `===` instead of  `==`. otherwise things like : `[-1,"chill",true] == "-1,chill,true"` are true

Comment: Will you please try it with angular 2 ? and his the probelm is  "It seems that my var gets the propper value but my *ngif does not work."

Comment: Do i understand correctly that `===` also checks the var type?

Comment: @VivekDoshi I'm not saying what you did doesn't work I'm just curious about why it works with `===` and not `==`

Comment: In javascript, the operator '==' only check equality and '===' check type and equality , yes @YounesM

Comment: And Angular is developed with typescript , so you should use === .

Comment: @sHamann , yes , you understand correctly that === also checks the var type

Comment: My pleasure , Will you please upvote the answer also please ?

Answer (score 2):

you can use [hidden] instead ngIf

```
<li class="navigation-items"> 
<button class="dropdown-header" (click)="onSelect()">Link 2</button> 
<div  class="dropdown-content" [hidden]="IsHidden">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

In Component

```
IsHidden= true;

onSelect(){
 this.IsHidden= !this.IsHidden;
}
```

Comment: This is not a good answer, `[hidden]` hides the component (using css) while `ngIf` removes it completely from the DOM. That could not match what OP's trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [hidden] instead ngIf

```
<li class="navigation-items"> 
    <button class="dropdown-header" (click)="onSelect()">Link 2</button> 
    <div  class="dropdown-content" [hidden]="IsHidden">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
```

In Component

```
IsHidden= true;

onSelect(){
this.IsHidden=true;
 this.IsHidden= !this.IsHidden;
}
```