# Showing a div based on button click

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

I'm trying to show a div based on whether button is clicked or not, however this doesn't seem to be working.

**Component HTML**

```
<button ng-click="showFormToggle()">Click</button>

<div ng-show="showForm">

</div>
```

I've also tried

```
<button (click)="showFormToggle()">Click</button>

<div *ngIf="showForm">

</div>
```

**Component Typescript**

```
 showForm: boolean = false;

 showFormToggle(){
    this.showForm = true;
    console.log(this.showForm);
  }
```

Comment: Your div is actually empty, You won't be able to know if it worked or not

Comment: By visual inspection, you could not tell, but if it worked, the div would be present in an inspector.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show / Hide - Content on Button Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43180943/show-hide-content-on-button-click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your Component HTML, you may be confused as the version of Angular you are using.  I am assuming you are intending to use Angular2+, considering your naming convention (Component vs Controller), and therefore the first example no longer works (That is AngularJS).
component.ts

```
showForm : boolean = false;
```

component.html

```
<button (click)="showForm = !showForm">Click</button>
<div *ngIf="showForm">
</div>
```

or

```
<button (click)="showForm = !showForm">Click</button>
<div [hidden]="!showForm">
</div>
```

Please confirm what you are using, Angular 2+ or AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

in your html:

```
<button (click)="showFormToggle()">Click</button>

            <div *ngIf="isChecked">
                Clicked!
            </div>
```

in your ts file, before the constructor:

```
isChecked = false;
```

and your function:

```
showFormToggle(){
    this.isChecked = !this.isChecked;
}
```

I hope it is what you are looking for!